# Converting from one template class to another (both derived from the same base class)

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, vector

I've searched around but couldn't find an answer to my question. I've been trying for some time now to make a conversion constructor to work in my derived classes, but I can't make it work no matter what I do.

To make it simple, I've got an abstract base class and two (soon more) derived classes that both use templates (they are vectors so they use templates to accept more than one type of element). One is a vector whose size is determined by a template parameter, and the other's size depends on the parameter used to create the object.

I want to be able to convert from one to the other using a conversion constructor. Here are the declarations for both classes. I think I should skip the implementation of the functions, since they are long and in my opinion irrelevant to the question, but if you think it's necessary, I will add it to the rest.

**This is the dynamic vector class**

```
template <class elem>
class Vect_variable : public Vect<elem>
{
    template <class T>
        friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const Vect_variable<T>&);

    template <class T>
        friend Vect_variable<T>& operator+ (T, const Vect_variable<T>&);
        // Pour les operations x+vecteur et pas vecteur+x avec int x

    template <class T>
        friend Vect_variable<T>& operator- (T, const Vect_variable<T>&);
        // Pour les operations x+vecteur et pas vecteur+x avec int x

    template <class T>
        friend Vect_variable<T>& operator* (T, const Vect_variable<T>&);
        // Pour les operations x+vecteur et pas vecteur+x avec int x

    public:
        Vect_variable(std::size_t sz = 0): taille(sz), vecteur(new elem[sz]) {};
        Vect_variable(std::size_t, const elem&);
        Vect_variable(const Vect_variable&);
        Vect_variable(Vect_variable&&);
        Vect_variable& operator=(const Vect_variable&);
        virtual elem& operator[] (std::ptrdiff_t nIndex);
        virtual const elem& operator[] (std::ptrdiff_t nIndex) const;
        virtual Vect_variable& operator+(); // + unaire
        virtual Vect_variable& operator-(); // - unaire
        virtual Vect_variable& operator+(const elem&); // + compos. par compos.
        virtual Vect_variable& operator-(const elem&); // - compos. par compos.
        virtual Vect_variable& operator*(const elem&); // * compos. par compos.
        virtual Vect_variable& operator+=(const elem&); // + compos. par compos.
        virtual Vect_variable& operator-=(const elem&); // - compos. par compos.
        virtual Vect_variable& operator*=(const elem&); // * compos. par compos.
        Vect_variable& operator+(const Vect_variable&); // + vect dynam.
        Vect_variable& operator-(const Vect_variable&); // - vect dynam.
        Vect_variable& operator*(const Vect_variable&); // * vect dynam.
        Vect_variable& operator+=(const Vect_variable&); // + vect dynam.
        Vect_variable& operator-=(const Vect_variable&); // - vect dynam.
        Vect_variable& operator*=(const Vect_variable&); // * vect dynam.
        ~Vect_variable () {delete[] vecteur ;}

    private:
        elem* vecteur;
        std::size_t taille;
};
```

**And here is the vector whose size is fixed by a template parameter**

```
template <class elem, std::size_t taille=10>

class Vect_fixe: public Vect<elem>
{
    template <class T, std::size_t D>
        friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const Vect_fixe<T, D>&);

    template <class T, std::size_t D>
        friend Vect_fixe<T,D>& operator+ (T, const Vect_fixe<T, D>&);
        // Pour les operations x+vecteur et pas vecteur+x avec int x

    template <class T, std::size_t D>
        friend Vect_fixe<T,D>& operator- (T, const Vect_fixe<T, D>&);
        // Pour les operations x+vecteur et pas vecteur+x avec int x

    template <class T, std::size_t D>
        friend Vect_fixe<T,D>& operator* (T, const Vect_fixe<T, D>&);
        // Pour les operations x+vecteur et pas vecteur+x avec int x


    public:
        Vect_fixe() = default;
        Vect_fixe(const elem&);
        virtual elem& operator[] (std::ptrdiff_t nIndex);
        virtual const elem& operator[] (std::ptrdiff_t nIndex) const;
        virtual Vect_fixe& operator+() ; // + unaire
        virtual Vect_fixe& operator-(); // - unaire
        virtual Vect_fixe& operator+(const elem&); // + compos. par compos.
        virtual Vect_fixe& operator-(const elem&); // - compos. par compos.
        virtual Vect_fixe& operator*(const elem&); // * compos. par compos.
        virtual Vect_fixe& operator+=(const elem&); // + compos. par compos.
        virtual Vect_fixe& operator-=(const elem&); // - compos. par compos.
        virtual Vect_fixe& operator*=(const elem&); // * compos. par compos.
        Vect_fixe& operator+(const Vect_fixe&); // + vecteur meme taille
        Vect_fixe& operator-(const Vect_fixe&); // - vecteur meme taille
        Vect_fixe& operator*(const Vect_fixe&); // * vecteur meme taille
        Vect_fixe& operator+=(const Vect_fixe&); // + vecteur meme taille
        Vect_fixe& operator-=(const Vect_fixe&); // - vecteur meme taille
        Vect_fixe& operator*=(const Vect_fixe&); // * vecteur meme taille

        std::size_t get_size();
        elem get_vecteur();

    private:
        elem vecteur[taille] = {0};
        std::size_t size = taille;

};
```

So I tried using a constructor that takes a parameter of the other class' type, however that doesn't seem to work because some of the template arguments from the other class are not declared (?), and if I declare them it just keeps saying invalid template parameter. I've toyed around a lot but I couldn't figure out the right way to do it. The vast knowledge of the internet was lacking (or perhaps my own researching ability was lacking), but I'm stuck.

Anyway, the general idea behind this is to use something of the sort:

```
Vect_variable(Vect_fixe<elem, taille>)
```

Or eventually any other way to convert from one type to the other.

Comment: forward declarations are your friend.

Comment: @RichardHodges You mean declaring before defining? Yes they are indeed. I am sorry if I come off as dense, but does that help me for the conversion?

Comment: added a complete compilable example as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forward declaration, possibly two levels of it are required:

```
#include <cstdint>

template<class Elem>
struct base
{

};

// forward declare classes
template<class Elem> struct variable;
template<class Elem, size_t N> struct fixed;

//forward declare members
template<class Elem> struct variable : base<Elem>
{
    variable() = default;
    template<size_t N> variable(const fixed<Elem, N>& r);

    variable& operator += (const variable& r);

    template<size_t N>
    variable& operator += (const fixed<Elem, N>& r);

};

template<class Elem, size_t N> struct fixed : base<Elem>
{
    fixed() = default;

};

// define members

template<class Elem>
template<size_t N>
variable<Elem>::variable(const fixed<Elem, N>& r)
{
    // implementation here
}

template<class Elem>
auto variable<Elem>::operator += (const variable& r) -> variable&
{
    // implementation here
    return *this;
}

template<class Elem>
template<size_t N>
auto  variable<Elem>::operator += (const fixed<Elem, N>& r) -> variable&
{
    // implementation here
    return *this;
}


using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    fixed<double, 10> fd;
    variable<double> vd(fd);

    vd += fd;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is indeed quite different than what I tried to do.

Comment: @DefinitelyNotMe just one last thing... don't do this. You are essentially duplicating the role of const and mutable which already exist as keywords. This is un-necessary. a "fixed_vector" is just a "const variable_vector".

Comment: Well, that's pretty much what I thought at first, but I don't have much of a choice since this is part of a greater project, and apparently both are needed. The future holds the answers I suppose.

Comment: Tell your lead developer that I wish him luck :-)

Comment: I am sorry, just a small question. In your implementation, both the fixed and variable classes use the same template, but in my case one of the templates has an additional argument (that defines the fixed vector's size), and that argument comes as not declared when I'm trying to declare the constructor. Is there a way to fix that?

edit- He is my teacher :D I will add that somewhere in my comments then

Comment: yes, what I am showing you is how to lay out the declarations. I will modify the example code to include a size on the fixed one. One moment.

Comment: @DefinitelyNotMe updated. now includes size in fixed template type, and shows you how to lay out the binary operators.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to convert from a `Vect_variable` to a `Vect_fixe`, the latter requires the size to be a template argument (so constant at compile time), but the only way to obtain the size of a `Vect_variable` is at runtime.

But I don't see any particular problems in converting from `Vect_fixe` to `Vect_variable`:

```
template<std::size_t size> Vect_variable(const Vect_fixe<elem,size>& other) : Vect_variable(size)
{ 
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  {
    (*this)[i] = other[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand templates well enough, but wouldn't it be similiar to creating an object with different template parameters? The size of the fixed vector can be changed, it just is part of the parameters one has to give when creating an object using the template. Wouldn't that be the same when using conversion? Just giving to the template the variable vector's size as parameter.